# Can't create new post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I click submit button it creates post with empty values. No problem when i create post in rails console. Any ideas?

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

posts.controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.save!
        redirect_to posts_path
    end

    private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :user_id)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If instead of doing Post.new(post_params) you do Post.new(params[:post]) does that work for you ?

Check in your server log what is sent you could find the issues there.